# TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'> when process dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I want to use `is_holiday()` in `chinesecalendar` library to judge holidays based on the information in the time column of dataframe (`datetime.date` is required to be passed).

I extract three integers from the dataframe and combine them into datetime.date, but TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>.

```
init_time_data["is_holiday"] = is_holiday(
           datetime.date(
                         init_time_data["记账日期"].dt.year.astype(int),
                         init_time_data["记账日期"].dt.month.astype(int),
                         init_time_data["记账日期"].dt.day).astype(int)
                        )
)
```

wrong:

```
File "F:\Anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 185, in wrapper
    raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this package but it seems the function is_holiday returns True/False based on an input datetime.

Since your column is already in datetime format, there's no need to convert it to int - you can just apply the function:

```
import pandas as pd
from chinese_calendar import is_holiday

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'datetime_col': [
        pd.to_datetime('2004-01-02'),
        pd.to_datetime('2012-03-04'),
        pd.to_datetime('2020-05-06'),
    ],
})

df['is_holiday'] = df['datetime_col'].apply(is_holiday)
```

Output:

```
    id  datetime_col    is_holiday
0   a   2004-01-02      False
1   b   2012-03-04      True
2   c   2020-05-06      False
```